# What is the difference between "I saw Sam playing." and "I saw Sam was playing."?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "I saw Sam playing." and "I saw Sam was playing."?

If first 'playing' is a gerund what is it expressing ? How is it different from the second sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

*I saw Sam playing.* Sam, in the act of playing, was one of the things I could see at that moment. If he was playing a game out of doors, I might be talking about the view from my window.

*I saw [that] Sam was playing.* From the evidence of my eyes, I became aware that Sam was playing. I might have been expecting that he wouldn't play that day.